# App Configuration for Facebook Login of website running from IIS localhost ----

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost, facebook-login, facebook-app-settings

Can anybody tell me/teach me a few things on this one? I need it very much.

[http://forums.asp.net/t/2081089.aspx?ASP+NET+Website+Facebook+Login+configuring+the+APP+settings+properly+to+get+the+login+working+through+localhost+IIS+]

Please offer me some knowledge guidance on how/what to do here.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't post only links. Describe your problems here and ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

- goto https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and create a new app
- select 'website' as your platform
- follow the next steps and you should be presented with an option to setup 'facebook login'.
- Later you will need to update the application under 'Settings'  ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/settings/ ) to setup the production environment URL

Comment: hi @sbsbessa.
I followed those steps, I set up my app primarily. What I need to know, is some specific things like:
should I specify 'localhost' in the domain?

Comment: hi @sbsbessa.
I followed those steps, set up my app primarily. What I need to know [if you had followed that link I posted], is some specific things like:

1. should I specify 'localhost' in the domain? or 'localhost/Jobacity' as domain?
the latter is unlikely,as it says 'top level domains are not allowed'.

2. redirect url, should it be 'localhost/Jobacity/Dashboard.aspx' [since the whole thing is running from IIS localhost] or some other qualified expression.

3. since by default the requests go through port 80, what do I do about mentioning a port number.

These are prime queries right now.

Comment: @VinoDivinoOsteriano 
1. you should specify localhost (or you local IP) as the domain
2. redirect url should be http://localhost/Jobacity/Dashboard.aspx (or replace localhost with your local IP if you used IP in 1.
3. you can include port in the URL like http://localhost:8080/Jobacity/Dashboard.aspx